# Centre and open infowindow by using External Links and Reset

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently creating a small map and below is the following code, but I want to be able to use an external link on the same page to make the map centre over a specific marker, but I dont know or what to search for, I'm guessing I need to create a listener but I need some guidance:

**EDIT:**
I managed to figure out how to add external link using:

```
//Button Controls
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("Map_GeoLocation"),"click", function() { map.setCenter(GeoMarker.getPosition() ); return false; } );
```

But I don't know how to make it work in an array :-/ you can see it here http://www.everythingcreative.co.uk/marker

**EDIT x2:**
I have cleaned up the code to make it easier to view but I still don't know how to make the buttons work with an external link. Also why does it not work with IE?

```
//Retina Images
var RetinaHotelMarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage("./assets/images/global/global_marker_hotel@2x.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(30,30));
var RetinaChurchMarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage("./assets/images/global/global_marker_church@2x.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(30,30));
var RetinaCrosshair = new google.maps.MarkerImage("./assets/images/global/global_marker_crosshair@2x.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(30,30));
var RetinaMarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage("./assets/images/global/global_marker@2x.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(30,30));

//Markers
var markers = [
    [1, 'Great Fosters', 51.416741,-0.543854, RetinaHotelMarker],
    [2, 'St Matthews', 51.432327,-0.459162, RetinaChurchMarker],
    // Staines
    [3, 'Travel Lodge Staines', 51.435698,-0.514469, RetinaMarker],
    [4, 'Thames Lodge Staines', 51.431498,-0.511444, RetinaMarker],
    [5, 'The Boleyn Staines', 51.43218,-0.516293, RetinaMarker],
    [6, 'The Swan Staines', 51.432534,-0.516422, RetinaMarker],
    // Surrey
    [7, 'The Runnymede Hotel', 51.43751,-0.537544, RetinaMarker],
    [8, 'The Wheatsheaf Hotel', 51.409151,-0.592704, RetinaMarker],
    [9, 'The Premier Inn Sunbury', 51.419322,-0.42248, RetinaMarker],
    [10, 'The Crown Chertsey', 51.39181,-0.501861, RetinaMarker],
    // Heathrow
    [11, 'Sofitel Heathrow', 51.473478,-0.49152, RetinaMarker],
    [12, 'Marriott Heathrow', 51.481263,-0.438209, RetinaMarker],
    [13,'Premier Inn Heathrow', 51.481615,-0.482288, RetinaMarker]
];

// Geolocation Success
function success(position) {

// Create Canvas
var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
mapcanvas.id = 'global_map_container';
document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

// Get Geolocation Lat/Lng
var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

// Create Geolocation Marker
var GeoMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: coords,
    map: map,
    icon:RetinaCrosshair,
    title:"You are here!",
});

// Map Options
var options = {
    zoom: 12,
    //center: coords,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.416741,-0.543854),
    mapTypeControl: false,
    navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

// Create Map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("global_map_container"), options);

// Marker Control
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// Marker Creation
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][2], markers[i][3]),
        map: map,
        flat: true,
        icon: markers[i][4]
    });

    // Find Bounds  
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

    // Marker Center
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            // Center on marker
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            infowindow.setContent(markers[i][1]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}

// Make Map fit all Markers
map.fitBounds(bounds);

//Button Controls
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("Map_GeoLocation"),"click", function() { 
    map.setCenter(GeoMarker.getPosition() );
});

}

// Run GeoLocation check
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
  error('Geo Location is not supported');
}
```

HTML:

```
<li><a href="#" id="Map_GeoLocation" class="global_crosshair"><span>Find Me</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="Map_Church" class="global_church"><span>The Church</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="Map_Hotel"class="global_hotel"><span>The Venue</span></a></li>
```